# how to calculate small-world index in weighted networks

Tags: r, functional-programming

I want to calculate the small-world index for weighted graphs. I have tried the smallworldness from qgraph, but in the original paper of Humphries 2008, this index (if I understood well) works on unweighted graphs.

the command from {qgraph} is:

```
smallworldness(x, B = 1000, up = 0.995, lo = 0.005)
```

where x is a graph
I wanted only the smallworldness as a value so I used:

```
small_test <- as.data.frame(smallworldness(wtest_graph, B = 1000, up = 0.995,       lo = 0.005))[1,1]
```

moreover, the tnet package doesn't involve a command for smallworldness

and when I tried to use igraph based on erdos.renyi.game, it wouldn't work, as there were too many edges (20x20, are they really too many?)

how can I calculate the smallworldness in weighted graphs?

Comment: Can you provide the equation that defines "swallworldness" for a graph? What code did you use?

Comment: the equation is sigma=gamma/ lambda,   where gamma=clustering coefficient(g)/clustering coefficient(random network with the same number of nodes as g) and lambda=mean shortest path length in g/ mean shortest path length in a random network with the same number of nodes as g.    sigma denotes the smallworldness value

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data, and the error your receive when you try this approach? I'm still not sure exactly what you are asking.